# How to upload a string value from PowerShell runbook (Azure Automation Account) to Azure Storage blob/fileshare?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I am working on Azure solution where on one step I'd like to use Azure Automation Account's runbook (PowerShell). I need to update an existing file content or create a new file with short string value as content. The problem is that every solution I've found leads to store a file with string on drive/location and after that it can be upload to AzStorage. Can You tell me Guys if it's possible to create a file in blob/file share from string directly from Automation Account runbook with PowerShell? Or maybe someone knows other simple solution.
Thank You

I've tried:
-to mount a drive on Azure Storage file share, and to store temporary file on that drive (works locally, but not on Azure Automation runbook)
-to create a file in memory and then upload it to blob/fileshare, but commands I've found expects a path to a source file

Answer (score 0):

> Can You tell me Guys if it's possible to create a file in blob/file share from string directly from Automation Account runbook with PowerShell?

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

Used below commands and followed [Microsoft-Documnet1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragecontext?view=azps-9.6.0) and [Microsoft-Document2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/set-azstorageblobcontent?view=azps-9.6.0):

```
$con = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "rithwik" -StorageAccountKey "40lwoOA/GfU0HoOJyNqvdBhM+AStdxrHjg=="
$y="How are you Rithwik !!!!!"
$y | Out-File -FilePath "vammo.txt"
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -File "vammo.txt" -Container "rithwik" -Blob "vammo.txt" -Context $con
```

[image]

Here `$con` is used for getting context

`$y` I have used to store the string I want to send

`vammo.txt` is the name of the file

Output:

After Running Automation Account:

[image]

In Storage Account:

[image]

Inside Blob:

[image]

Comment: Thank You so much :) Just an hour ago I've found that Azure Automation has a built-in storage. I've saved a file with my variable there and uploaded it to Azure Storage. That solution also works well, but yours is much better. Thanks once more.

Comment: Glad it solved your problem